# C++ Find the middle value of any inputted data type using function templates?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I've run into a bit of snag with this it seemed simple enough at first but now I just can't seem to work it out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

So the question is: a user inputs three values of data type either, int, float, or char.  The program then has to return the middle value.

Here is what i have so far:

The exercise requires that I use a function template and nothing like an array.

Header File:

```
#ifndef MIDTEMP_H
#define MIDTEMP_H

template <class T>
T doMiddle(T param, T param2, T param3)
{
   if ((param<param2 && param>param3) || (param<param3 && param>param2) || (param == param2 == param3))
    {
       return param;
    }
   else if ((param2<param && param2>param3) || (param2<param3 && param2>param) || (param2 == param == param3))
    {
      return param2;
    }
   else if ((param3<param2 && param3>param) || (param3<param && param3>param2) || (param3 == param2 == param))
    {
      return param3;
    }
   else if (param == param2 && param < param3)
    {
      return param;
    }

}

#endif
```

This now is the code which will test my header function:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Middle.h"
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
cout << "Please enter 3 integers. IF input is incorrect please input until correct." << endl;
cout << endl;
int a, b, c;
while (!(cin >> a >> b >> c))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}
cout << "The Middle is: " << doMiddle(a, b, c) << endl;
cout << endl;

//=======================================================

cout << "Please enter 3 floating point values.  IF input is incorrect please input until correct." << endl;
cout << endl;
float d, e, f;
while (!(cin >> d >> e >> f))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}
cout << "The Middle is: " << doMiddle(d, e, f) << endl;
cout << endl;

//=======================================================

cout << "Please enter 3 characters. IF input is incorrect please input until correct." << endl;
cout << endl;
char g, h, j;
while (!(cin >> g >> h >> j))
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}
cout << "The Middle is: " << doMiddle(g, h, j) << endl;
cout<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

So it works decently but lets say I do this (from cmd):

Please enter 3 integers. IF input is incorrect please input until correct.

5
3.2
6
2
The Middle is: 2

Please enter 3 floating point values.  IF input is incorrect please input until

9.0
9
9.0
The Middle is: -1.#IND

Please enter 3 characters. IF input is incorrect please input until correct.

r
r
r
The Middle is: r

why is it returning that -1.#IND value and is there some other way of doing this without those ridiculous if statements?

Comment: Whenever you have repetitive code that only differs in a number on a variable name, you should consider an array. When you have repetitive code that only differs in a type, you should consider putting one set in a function and making the type a template parameter.

Comment: Yeah my first choice would have been to use an array but the exercise requires me to do it without.  And with a template function.

Comment: Use `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max())` to clear all invalid characters from the input. You can wrap this horror in a function.

Comment: great Thank you!  I'v got a lab in a few minutes but Ill try it soon enough and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function prints `-1.#IND` because your template function does not return a value if all check fail(which occurs if all values are the same).

When all values inputed are the same, `(param == param2 == param3)` will always evaluate to `false` because `param == param2` evaluates to a bool and a bool(true for example) is not equal to 9.0(from your example).

The template method then exits without returning and you get garbage out from the stack when you print.

Your check for equality should really be the first one like:

```
if ((param == param2) && (param2 == param3))
    return param;
```

Then you go on checking for the middle value and don't forget to return something in a last `else` case.

Speaking of checking, your logic is flawed if only 2 values are equal. You should also be cautious about comparing `float` values directly since some near values might be represented as the same float value.

Comment: thank you very much i figured the error was some where in the header file but I was unsure were.  I see what you mean about my logic I'll be sure to fix that up as well.

Comment: Couldnt up vote but it did answer my question so again thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
T doMiddle(T t1, T t2, T t3){
  T arr[]={t1,t2,t3};
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  std::nth_element( begin(arr), begin(arr)+1, end(arr) );
  return arr[1];
}
```

would do the trick.  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Id like to but The assignment requires thai i not use arrays